# Does MATLAB calculate parameters unlisted in the result list of arguments?

Tags: matlab, function-calls

We know that MATLAB supports functions outputting multiple results in a matrix.

For example, `[J, grad] = linearRegCostFunction(X, y, theta, lambda)`  returns `[J, grad]` if both parameters appear on the left-hand side like `[P, Q]`.
But when `grad` is missing, calling `P=linearRegCostFunction(X, y, theta, lambda)` would still give me the `J` value for my variable `P`.

Now my question is, does MATLAB spend computational resources calculating `grad` but simply not return it, or does it actually "realize" that only one of the result parameters is needed and skips the calculation for all the unlisted parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends. In particular, a MATLAB function may do different things depending on how many arguments you're asking for; see `nargout`.

Comment: Check the function's code. If it checks `nargout` to decide what to and avoid omputing non-used outputs, you'll notice that in the code. If it doesn't do that, it is computing everything, and then you are just dismissing some outputs

Comment: Ah I see... So I guess it's not considered good programming practice to not use 'nargout' for multiple output arguments, since it'll be wasting time calculating non-used ones...

Thanks for your help guys!